# Orientability of Stiefel manifold V2(R4)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, manifolds, orientation

What is an easy proof of orientability of Stiefel manifold $V_2(\mathbb{R}^4)$ (pairs of orthonormal vectors from $\mathbb{R}^4$ - subset of $\mathbb{R}^8$)? All proofs I found deal with Lie groups and other complicated for me stuff.

Answer (score 3):

What is not complicated? E.g., taking the first vector is a projection $V_2\to S^3\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ to the unit sphere, the fiber being the unit sphere in the tangent bundle to $S^3$. The latter is orientable as so is the normal bundle. Thus, orientable bundle over orientable sphere is orientable.